# Firefox and PHP htmlspecialchars / htmlentities

Tags: firefox

i have detect a problem with Firefox and PHP htmlspecialchars / htmlentities. The Problem ist in Firefox context menu "View Selection Source". In this view, encoded quotes and double quotes to HTML entities are displayed decoded.

```
HTML input field string: "<'&'>"

echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['string'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
// In Firefox webpage: "<'&'>"
// In Firefox "View Selection Source": "&lt;'&amp;'&gt;"

echo str_replace("&", "& ", htmlspecialchars($_POST['string'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
// In Firefox webpage: & quot;& lt;& #039;& amp;& #039;& gt;& quot;
// In Firefox "View Selection Source": & quot;& lt;& #039;& amp;& #039;& gt;& quot;
```